# SQL select distinct only highest values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

Lets say we have such table:

[image: table]

i only what to select unique plans with highest time, and also being able to select other columns. To ilustrate here's a query(witch obviously wouldn't work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(plan), time, id
FROM table
ORDER BY time desc
```

how can i get such table:

```
plan|time|id
----+----+--------
1   |0   |9
2   |90  |10
3   |180 |11
4   |360 |12
5   |720 |13
6   |1080|15
7   |0   |16
8   |720 |23
```

Comment: Is highest time unique per plan? Which of rows should be chosen when two highest times are found? This is important if you wish to select more data in a row.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek as you can see in table high time is not unique per plan, see plan id 7

Comment: Then you need another condition to differentiate between such rows (ie. `min(id)`).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

SELECT  plan, max(time), id
FROM demo group by plan

[check fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7483c/7)

Comment: Removed the redundant parenthesis. `DISTINCT` is **not** a function.

Comment: Other than that, this query is just wrong - even illegal if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled.

Comment: what's wrong? I think it works without DISTINCT, is it required here?

Comment: yes it works with distinct and also without distinct i just add a group by clause to you code...

Comment: the edits. It's just that in my case i dont use any functions

Comment: i just want to improve the answer thats all,that why i added the fiddle also it take time.any way i think you understand the answer

Comment: How is this even the answer, if it does not produce "unique plans with highest time"?? And fiddle is based on MySQL which behaves quite differently with aggregation?

Comment: This answer has several problems - that don't fit in the small comment space. It needs to be downvoted to -10 and/or deleted.

Comment: please just look at the answer

Comment: I did. Have you looked at your answer and **your** fiddle? Check again the line with `id=9`. You query gives as result a row that **does not** exist at the table data: **[your SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1c17/17)**

Comment: @ypercube....i didnt understand the mistake explain it to me...its not possible to delete this question because its accepted.so i will correct it...

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a simple aggregate query:

```
SELECT   plan, MAX(time)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY plan
```

Comment: this is ok, but what should i do if i whant to select more columns?

Comment: It depends, for instance the GROUP BY clause removes duplicated results based on a condition... you asked for uniqueness

Answer (score 3):

**If highest time is unique per plan**, and you need to select more columns, then a self join should do

```
select mytable.* from
mytable
inner join
  (
  select plan, max(time) as maxtime
  from mytable
  group by plan
  ) as maxtimes
  on mytable.plan = maxtimes.plan and mytable.time = maxtimes.maxtime
```

Comment: doesn't work. Some rows have same plan id and same time, so they are being duplicated

Comment: ow, yea, you wrote that, sorry